# Кладр и иерархия регионов

Tags: дерево, алгоритм, кладр

Есть такая штука -- kladr(взято [тут](http://www.gnivc.ru/inf_provision/classifiers_reference/kladr/)), "бд" где лежат все регионы и облости нашей Необъятной.
Нужно построить дерево иерархии этих регионов, но что-то весь день угробил так и не разобрался как это сделать.

Answer (score 2):

Мой вариант. Скорее всего где-то найдётся баг, да и вообще говнокодеще, но мою задачу решает.

```
<?php

try
{
    $PDO = new PDO("mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=test", 'login', 'pass');
    $STH = $PDO->query("SELECT *  FROM kladr");
    $STH->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    while ($k = $STH->fetch())
    {

        parseCode($k);
        getLevel($k);
        $p = getParent($k, $PDO);
        $STH3 = $PDO->prepare("
            INSERT IGNORE INTO regions
            (region_id, region_name, parent,level)
            VALUES 
            ('{$k->id}','" . $k->socr . '. ' . $k->sname . "', '" . (empty($p) ? NULL : $p->id) . "','{$k->level}')");

        if (!$STH3->execute())
        {
            $a = $STH3->errorInfo();
            throw new Exception($a[2]);
        }

        print $k->id . "\n";
    }
}
catch (Exception $e)
{
    print $e->getMessage();
    print $e->getTrace();
}

function parseCode($k)
{
    $k->codeParts[1] = substr($k->code, 0, 2);
    $k->codeParts[2] = substr($k->code, 2, 3);
    $k->codeParts[3] = substr($k->code, 5, 3);
    $k->codeParts[4] = substr($k->code, 8, 3);
    $k->codeParts[5] = substr($k->code, 11, 2);
    //5й всего-лишь признак того что есть альтернативное назваение
}

function getLevel($k)
{
    for ($level = 5; $level >= 1; $level--)
    {

        if ($k->codeParts[$level] != 0)
        {
            $k->level = $level;
            return;
        }
    }
}

function getParent($k, $PDO, $ignoreLevel = NULL)
{
    $parentCode = '';
    foreach ($k->codeParts as $level => $codePart)
    {
        if ($level != $ignoreLevel)
        {
            if ($level != $k->level)
            {
                $parentCode .= $codePart;
            }
            else
            {
                $parentCode .= ($k->level == 1 || $k->level == 5) ? '00' : '000';
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $parentCode = str_pad($parentCode, 13, '0');
            break;
        }
    }

    $STH2 = $PDO->query("SELECT *  FROM kladr WHERE code = '{$parentCode}'");
    $STH2->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    $p = $STH2->fetch();

    if (empty($p) && $k->level > 1)
    {
        if ($ignoreLevel < 0)
        {
            return $p;
        }
        $p = getParent($k, $PDO, is_null($ignoreLevel) ? $k->level - 1 : $ignoreLevel - 1);
    }
    return $p;
}

?>
```